# using .pipe() in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm unclear on what the .pipe() function does in node?

How could I use it to refactor any of the two functions below?

```
exports.collectData = function(req, callback) {
    var data = "";

    req.on("data", function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    })

    req.on("end", function() {
        callback(data);
    })
}

http.createServer(function(req, res){
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-type": "text/plain"});
res.write("Howdy");
res.end();
}).listen(port);
```

//new code from answer:

```
var fs = require("fs");

    // Read File
    fs.createReadStream("input/people.json")
        // Write File
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("output/people.json"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.pipe` connects the readable side of a stream with the writeable side of another stream:

```
readable.pipe(writable)
```

I.e. it's a way to pass data from one stream to another. It's the Node equivalent to IUnix pipes:

```
foo | bar
```

---

> How could I use it to refactor any of the two functions below?

Since you don't seem to connect two streams there is no need to use `.pipe`.

Comment: @devdropper87: Yes. I recommend to read https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook .